# How to reinstall database on Prestahop Module?

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I'm trying to customize a Prestashop module and I need to add two new colonnes in a table.

The problem is that the database is already created, I guess it did when  the module initializing. So if I change the code now,  changes does not appear and I keep receiving this mistake:

[image]

There is no way to do it in configuration and I suppose if I delete the module my code will dissepear.

How can I do ?

Maybe asking the delete and the create method  in a common method (just one time).

I'm new with Smarty and PHP,  I see it's not a usual method where the table is created.

Could you help me ?

I'm new with Smarty, how can I do that ?
It looks like it's not a method where the table is created.

```
$sql = array();
$sql[] =
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `'._DB_PREFIX_.'opartdevis` (
        `id_opartdevis` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `id_shop` int(10) NOT NULL,
        `id_cart` int(10) NOT NULL,
        `id_customer` int(10) NOT NULL,
        `name` varchar(128),
        `message_visible` TEXT,
        `id_customer_thread` int(10),
        `date_add` DATETIME NOT NULL,
        `status` int(2) DEFAULT 0,
        `id_order` int(10) NULL,
        `id_ordered_cart` int(10) NULL,
        `remise` int(10),
        `delivery` int(10),
        PRIMARY KEY (`id_opartdevis`)
    ) ENGINE='._MYSQL_ENGINE_.' DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8';

//1.6.1.0 specific price bug fix
if (version_compare(_PS_VERSION_, '1.6.1.0', '=')) {
    $sql[] = "ALTER TABLE "._DB_PREFIX_."specific_price DROP INDEX id_product_2";
    $sql[] = "ALTER TABLE "._DB_PREFIX_."specific_price ADD INDEX id_product_2 (id_product,id_shop,id_shop_group,id_currency,id_country,id_group,id_customer,id_product_attribute,from_quantity,id_specific_price_rule,id_cart,`from`,`to`)";
}

foreach ($sql as $s) {
    if (!Db::getInstance()->execute($s)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Malaury

Comment: This code is in your `install()` function of the PS module?

Comment: Yes it is: `` include(dirname(__FILE__).'/sql/install.php');```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to revert all DB changes when you're uninstalling the module.

Define (or append to existing) `uninstall()` function in your base module file and run `DROP TABLE` query on the created table. Example:

```
public function uninstall() {
    if (!parent::uninstall()) {
        return false;
    }

    $sql = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `'._DB_PREFIX_.'opartdevis`';
    if (!Db::getInstance()->execute($sql)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This way, when you're uninstalling the module, the table is going to be deleted (and recrteated when you install it again).